# Can't dismiss keyboard, UITextField delegate being called OK

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

This problem has been driving me crazy.  It seems no matter what I try I cannot get the keyboard to hide once it is shown in my simple Swift program.

It does not work when I resignFirstResponder() in textFieldShouldReturn nor does it work when handing a background touch by calling endEditing() from touchesBegan(...).  I can see these respective methods are all being called when I set debugger break points to them, so the delegate is properly set and being called as expected.

Here are the specific steps I took:

- Create a new single-view application Swift project
- Drag a UITextField onto the view, wire up the IBOutlet, and set the ViewController up as UITextFieldDelegate.
- Run in iPhone 6 Simulator or on an iPhone 6 device
- Once the keyboard is presented, it is never dismissed!!

I am out of ideas - what am I missing???

Here is the entire contents of my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      myTextField.delegate = self
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
      self.view.endEditing(true)
  }

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
      return
  }

  func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
      return false
  }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `'false'` from `'textFieldShouldEndEditing'`. The following is an excerpt from the `'UITextFieldDelegate'` documentation:

> **Return Value**
>
> YES if editing should stop; otherwise, NO if the editing session
>   should continue
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method is called when the text field is asked to resign the first
>   responder status. This might occur when your application asks the text
>   field to resign focus or when the user tries to change the editing
>   focus to another control. Before the focus actually changes, however,
>   the text field calls this method to give your delegate a chance to
>   decide whether it should.
>
> Normally, you would return YES from this method to allow the text
>   field to resign the first responder status. You might return NO,
>   however, in cases where your delegate detects invalid contents in the
>   text field. By returning NO, you could prevent the user from switching
>   to another control until the text field contained a valid value.
>
> [Source](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldEndEditing:)

So, either return `'true'` from it or remove the method completely, unless you really need to do something useful inside it. `'textFieldDidBeginEditing'`and `'touchesBegan'` should also probably be removed. I'm really surprised that the same code worked in Objective-C.

Comment: Oh for the love of... I had cut and pasted the set of UITextDelegate methods from some sample code and had totally ignored the other methods, presuming they were innocuous boilerplate.  And you are 100% correct, when I whipped up the 'equivalent' test in Obj-C, I just implemented the callback I was interested in, and left off the others, so it worked fine.  Duh!